# C++ - Overloading vs Overriding in Inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding, overloading

As far as I learned, Overriding is when you have 2 functions which have the same name and function return type (`void`, `int`, `float`.. etc) and the same parameter numbers and types.

And the overloading is when you have 2 functions which have the same name but either Parameter number/types or function return type should be different.

But today when I was in the class, I saw this slide:

[image]
Shouldn't this be overloading? Not overriding? Because here the return type changed (from `void`
to `float`) and fa1() function in the base class had no parameter, but in the derived class it has float parameter.

If this is overriding, why?

Comment: `ia1` doesn't override, it simply hides the member in the base class (this is dodgy and should never be done in real code). Also you're correct, the function is overloaded, not overridden.

Comment: `fa1` is not `virtual`. Good luck with the overriding. The slide gets back to this problem when it brings up hiding later, but on the whole I hate this slide. Too misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, any method in a derived class only overrides the method in the base class if their declarations match (I say "match" but I don't know the formal term for that). That is, all arguments must have the same type, and `const` qualification of `this` must be the same. If anything there mismatches, the method in the derived class *hides* all methods with the same name, instead of overriding. This is what the "ERROR" in your picture tries to tell you. So `// overrides` in a comment in that picture is incorrect and misleading.

Yes, many C++ teachers actually don't understand these somewhat obscure details.

BTW additionally, if you want to override, the method in your base class should be `virtual`; otherwise, polymorphism won't work. If it was not `virtual`, we also say that the derived-class method *hides* the base-class method. Here, however, the part about *hiding* has almost no meaning; what this term really wants to express is that you're not overriding.

In addition, *overloading* is, as you noticed, presence of several methods with the same name but different signatures. They should all be present in the derived class to be useful - if the derived class has only one method `fa1`, and the other `fa1` are in the base, they will be hidden. However, there is syntax sugar which "copies" all `fa1` from base to derived, disabling all that *hiding* semantics:

```
class A
{
public:
    void fa1();
    void fa1(int);
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    using A::fa1;
    void fa1(int, int);
};

...
B b;
b.fa1(); // calls A::fa1()
b.fa1(4); // calls A::fa1(int)
b.fa1(4, 8); // calls B::fa1(int, int)
```

---

The part about hiding is rarely, if ever, useful. When overriding, you should tell this to your compiler - use the `override` keyword for that. The compiler will then check that your code works as you intended.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void fa1(int) {}
    void fa2(int) {}
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void fa1(int) override {} // OK
    void fa1() override {} // ERROR: doesn't really override - different signature
    void fa2(int) override {} // ERROR: doesn't really override - not virtual in base
};
```

Comment: Good answer, but one detail: A function in a derived class never overrides a non-virtual function in a base class, even if the parameter types, cv-qualifiers, and ref-qualifiers are all exactly the same. "Override" can only apply when the base function is virtual.

Answer (score 0):

`ia1` not overloading. First you can't overload variables. So `ia1` is definitely an override. And it's also a dangerous thing. At my company, our coding standards disallow overriding variable names in any situation. It just leads to confusion.

`fa1` though -- that looks like an overload. The base class `fa1()` takes no arguments, but the subclass version takes a float.

Comment: "ia1 is definitely an override" - no, you can neither "override" nor "overload" variables. The right term is "shadow".